# My apple account and gmail account are messing up my email

Tags: iphone, icloud, email, gmail

I have a registered apple account ending in @me.com and a gmail account as well. This is causing extremely frustrating email problems as I am not able to view any emails sent to my @me account on my phone email and they don't show up in my gmail other places so I am missing important emails. How do I get rid of this damn @me account or at least solve this mixing problem?

Comment: Please clarify. You have two different email addresses? Or just the gmail? Are you using the MobileMe account just for iCloud backups or email as well?

Comment: Do you have both email accounts set up? Go to Settings, and then click "Mail, Contacts, Calendars". Let us know if you have an iCloud account with the @me address as well as the Gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, MobileMe (@me) has been changed to iCloud. Update your settings in Mail, Contacts, and Calendars. If you don't use the iCloud (MobileMe) account for email, just switch off email and leave Calendars and Contacts selected.